# Can i send a 2 byte size variable as 1 byte size variable?

Tags: python, c, byte

I am working on some ADC(Analog-to-Digital) value conversions and need to send those values over the UART but due to the speed and other size limitations I want to convert those to one byte size

The ADC is 12 bit for a range 0.0 to 5.0.

Currently I am splitting the 2 byte variable to two separate bytes and joining them back in the receiver section

Sending (C)

```
// i am trying to send 0xFF8 (4088) which is read from that register 
send[0] = (VADC_G5RES4.B.RESULT) >> 8 ;
send[1] = (VADC_G5RES4.B.RESULT) & 0x0FF;
 .
send[30] = .....
```

Receiving (Python)

```
adc1 = data[3]
adc1 = adc1 << 8 | data[4]
adc1 = (float(adc1 * 5) / 4096)
# gives me 4.990234 as the value
```

Is there any way that i can send the value in just one byte (maybe by performing the calculation on the sending side)

Only 2 digits after the decimal (4.99) would be fine

Comment: I don't see how you can encode it in a single byte. - The 0-5 requires 3 bits, and 0-99 requires more than 5 bits.

Comment: How many bits in the high-order byte are significant?  I.e. is this actually a 16 bit ADC or something less.

Comment: Provide range and required resolution.

Comment: @SaiGanesh : Then the assumptions in my answer are correct.  You can retain a precision of 0.02 for a range 0 to 5 in 8 bits.

Comment: You should add the information about the ADC and real-world units range to the question rather then in comments.  It is important to the question and a useful answer.

Comment: Is it correct that both send[0] and send[1] are calculated form `VADC_G5RES4.B.RESULT` (in which case id the order of reading critical, or is that just a typo?)

Comment: I edited your question; the fact that the ADC is 12 bit and the range 0 to 5 is critical to a useful and accurate answer.  You should also include information about the nature of the signal - what is being measured, the signal bandwidth, what is the sample rate and what is the speed or capacity of the data link?  It would then be better to ask how you can send the data with minimal loss. A more open question will get you better answers.  Instead you have chosen an impossible solution, and asked how to make it  work, when what you need to do is ask for a solution that is possible.

Answer (score 7):

If there were some magic way to stuff two-byte values into one-byte values, we would do it to everything, and then we would do it again, and we would keep doing it and keep halving the size of everything until we were shoving all the world's information into a single byte. Such magic is not possible.

If you instead throw away half your data, you can reduce the size of things, but you say you want at least 2 digits after the decimal point. A byte can only encode 256 different values, and encoding everything from 0.00 to 9.99 takes 1000 different values, so you still can't do it.

---

**UPDATE**: With the additional information that these are only 12-bit values, rather than 16-bit, and that the maximum value is 5.0, we can do a lot better, though still not quite 3 significant figures in 8 bits.

First, instead of wasting 4 bits per value, we can pack 2 values into 3 bytes. That'd look something like

```
def pack(val1, val2):
    byte1 = val1 >> 4
    byte2 = ((val1 & 0xf) << 4) | (val2 >> 8)
    byte3 = val2 & 0xff
    return byte1, byte2, byte3
```

You might need to deal with a trailing half-byte.

If 1.5 bytes per value is still too much, there are lossy encoding options. For example, we can just throw away the 4 least-significant bits of every value:

```
encoded = val >> 4
```

and decode appropriately:

```
decoded = encoded * 5.0 / 256
```

This keeps a precision of 5/256, or about 0.02. Other encodings might perform better, depending on what you expect the signal to look like. For example, [chux's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364741/can-i-send-a-2-byte-size-variable-as-1-byte-size-variable/34365430#34365430) encodes values exactly as long as the values don't change too fast, but only has a precision of about 0.04 when the values are changing quickly.

Comment: Hahahahahhaahahahah!  +1.  I wish I could +more.

Comment: I just wanted to represent (either fake represent ) a two byte value to a one byte, i din't mean stuffing two bytes into one byte , just searching for a possibility

Comment: @SaiGanesh: Ehm, ... it is exactly what you are asking for: "Can i send a 2 byte size variable as 1 byte size variable"

Comment: It may not be necessary to discard as much as half the data; outside of HiFi audio, few ADC are 16 bit.

Comment: @iharob : It is not that smart an answer, because it just says "no", where a smart answer would be "no, but here's what you can do".  As other answers show there are solutions that may be suitable.  The simple solution yields 0.02 precision, the best solution can potentially  retain all the original data.  Its not magic, but it is possible.

Comment: @Clifford: The information that this is a 12-bit signal only arrived about half an hour after my answer, and that information is necessary for getting anywhere close to the precision the questioner wants in a single byte. Someone more familiar with EE probably could have guessed it wasn't 16-bit (and in retrospect, if I'd remembered reading [this HNQ](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199548/why-do-adcs-use-10-bit-rather-than-8-or-16), I could have guessed the same), but with a 16-bit value, "no" was pretty much the answer.

Comment: @user2357112 : I appreciate that the question was not clear and encouraged the OP to improve it.  In that case you might perhaps have stated your assumptions.  In context it was possible perhaps to make a best assumption of 12 bit and a range 0 to 5 by the use of 12 bit masks example values.  I have no real problem with your answer, although perhaps somewhat mocking in tone, it was more the praise that was heaped upon it by that seemed unwarranted.

Comment: Two full resolution values in 3 bytes -- good point; if the performance is marginal, this may be a useful solution.  An upvote for that. There may still be an issue of synchronisation with the stream on an unreliable link (knowing which byte is which).  Note that the sending end is C not Python.

Answer (score 3):

Use temporal compression.

Trade time for accuracy.  When the ADC is changing fast, sent a 7-bit approximation.  When it changes slow, send the delta.

The following is a coarse implementation idea.

Assume 2-byte ADC value in the ranges 0-3FFF.

```
 sample = ADC();
 encode_value = sample >> 7;
 send(encode_value);
 diff = sample - (encode_value << 7);

 loop:
   previous_sample = sample
   sample = ADC();
   diff = previous_sample - sample;
   if (diff >= -64 && diff <= 63)  {
     send(diff | 0x80);
     diff = 0;
   } else {
     encode_value = sample >> 7;
     send(encode_value);
     diff = sample - (encode_value << 7);
   }
```

// Receive

```
valid = 0;
loop:
  sample = receive()
  if (sample & 0x80) {
    delta = sample & 0x7F
    if (delta & 0x40) delta -= 128;
    ADC += delta;
  } else {
    ADC = sample << 9;
    valid = 1;
  }
```

Likely should reserve another bit to detect a missed sequence when sending a delta.  Other considerations apply, yet here it is to give the OP another point of view.

Refinements include having the `delta` give up 2 bits of `mantissa` for a 2-bit exponent.

---

[Edit]

12 bits of random data do not fit in 8 bits.  Some ideas:

1. Give up precision.  Simple divide the 12-bit value by 16, send those 8 bits and multiply by 16 on the receiving end.
2. Send the first A/D sample in 2 parts by cutting the 12-bit value into 2 6-bits halves.  Use the MSB to distinguish if the upper or lower is sent.  The receiving end needs 2 samples to put things back together.  The 2nd A/D sample on the transmits end is thrown away.
3. Like #2, but send 2 out of every 3 samples.  24-bits of data in 3 8-bit messages.
4. As answered in the beginning of this answer. Sometimes sending the course value, other times, the delta.
5. As commented below [@Clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34364741/can-i-send-a-2-byte-size-variable-as-1-byte-size-variable/34365430#comment56473736_34365430) always send a signed 8-bit delta.  Might need a minor adjustment to insure any bias in the receiving sum eventually works its way out.
6. Take a couple 1000 (million) samples and write it as packed 12-bit data into a file.  Zip (compress) the file.  What every the ration of compression is found, is an indicator of the best compression scheme we could derive.  If it is not at least 33%, then you best to accept that data is too dynamic to be completely transmitted with the requirements given.

Comment: Very good - wish I'd suggested that - I've even done it years ago sending telephone quality audio at 8ksps and 4 bits per sample.

Comment: @Clifford Similar experience.  The trick was to periodical insure the sender sent a non-delta value in case the receiver missed a message.

Comment: For audio signals with known bandwidth it is not necessary to send a non-delta, you just get a DC offset that can be removed either digitally or in the analogue.  Alternatively you wait until a zero-crossing before starting to send the data.  In this case the work was actually all done by a codec chip, the 12MHz 8051 in the project would not have been up to it - this was about 1990.

Comment: It occurs to me that with only a 7 bit absolute reference, while this technique maintains full resolution, its absolute precision will only be about 0.04.  It is good for signals (audio for example), but perhaps less good for precision monitoring (battery voltage for example).  It would be possible perhaps to send the references in two bytes - you may only need to send one at the start if the signal is sufficiently bandwidth limited (i.e. cannot change too fast).

Comment: Note that the OP has added in a comment that the ADC is only 12 bit (0 to 0xFFF)

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done without loosing bits and therefore precision.  Essentially you would need treat your ADC as if it were 8 bit.  That may not be as bad as it sounds, for example, if your ADC is 12 bit (not clear in your question), you loose just 4 bits.

```
uint8_t send = (adc_high_byte << 6) | (adc_low_byte >> 2) ;
```

then in the receiver:

```
adc1 = (data * 5.0) / 256 ;
```

In your example 4088 is sent as 4088/16 = 255 and at the receiver it is transformed:

```
(255 * 5.0) / 256 = 4.98
```

but note that

```
(254 * 5.0) / 256= 4.96,
```

so you end up with a precision of approximately 0.02 (precisely speaking, if your maximum value represented by 255 is 5.0, then the precision is 5.0/256 = 0.01953125).  This compares to the original precision of 5/4096 = 0.00122

A further refinement is possible using [*companding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding). In some applications, such as audio, it is more important to retain detail a small signal levels than high, so you can transform the 12 bit data to 8 using a non-linear encoding so that the difference between say 0 and 1 is much smaller than between 254 and 255.  The applicability and success of this will be application dependent - it works well for audio.  In other applications a different non-linear encoding may be appropriate, for example for battery monitoring you might use high resolution at the knee of the discharge curve, where rate of voltage drop increases rapidly (in some battery chemistries).

Finally as suggested by @chux, you can transmit delta (changes in level) in fewer bits and retain the full resolution (with some loss of absolute accuracy), but that was his suggestion so I won't elaborate, except to say that the technique can be used with companding.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly deciphered your problem, it seems that:

- you have values in the range `0x000` - `0xfff`
- you will make some math with those values (`(val * 5) / 4096` ) and you will not care about what comes after the first two decimals after the comma of the resulting number

If this is your question, you can first of all verify how much information you lose if you throw away the least significant hex digit from your values after the math:

```
>>> (0x010 * 5) / 4096
0.01953125
```

This means that if you spare it, you will have an error of ~0.02.

If you are ok with that, you can then encode your value in a single byte.
You just need to right-shift by 4 your value before sending:

```
 0    f    f    8      >> 4 =   [  0    0  ] f    f
0000 1111 1111 1000             [ 0000 0000]1111 1111
```

That is possible because you already had a vacant leading half-byte, and
are now freeing another half at the end.

On the receiving side, you will left-shift it again and then do the calculations:

```
>>> b = 0xff << 4
>>> (b * 5) / 4096
4.98046875
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert those in the sending side  and multiply with 2 and join a '.' at the 2nd position.. This method works( but not very accurate)

```
(4088*5)/4096 = 4.990234
```

use the first 3 digits and remove the decimal point

```
499
```

divide the value by 2 so that it can be sent using one signed byte (0-255)

```
499/2 = 249
```

send the value using your regular data transfer method

```
send[0] = 249
```

On receiving section multiply the value with 2 and add a decimal point

```
adc1 = 249*2
newvalue= adc1[:1]+'.'+adc1[1:]
# you get newvalue = 4.98 ( But you loose the accuracy of the converted adc values )
```

Comment: This reduces the resolution. OP seems to want to keep it, though

Comment: That is an inefficient method that unnecessarily looses data.  It is better to work in binary scales - it does not need to be in decimal until presentation/display.  Essentially to convert the 12 bit to 8 bit you divide the value by 16, and loose exactly 4 bits so makes the most effective use of teh available 8 bits.